# java Programming method calling method didn't get it

Tags: java, android

R.layout.main.. is like a nested class although i know this creating an object and using it to reference the class object    obj.me() & obj.var 
also have seen something like this but does not know what it means 
method1().method2();   is it like method calling a method

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are referencing is either something known as a Fluent Interface, or more generally a Builder Pattern. You will see syntax like this used during the construction of an object:

```
// Taken from DynamoDB Mapper Documentation
DynamoDBQueryExpression<PostedByMessage> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<PostedByMessage>()
.withIndexName("PostedBy-Message-Index")
.withConsistentRead(false)
.withKeyConditionExpression("PostedBy = :v1 and begins_with(Message, :v2)")
.withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```

There is an excellent article by Martin Fowler that describes how to construct a fluent interface, as well as the advantages and disadvantages of using one: https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html

This is closely related to the idea of a "Builder Pattern" for class construction. The general idea, is that instead of using a constructor and then setters for each field; you instead allow any field that isn't required at construction be 'set' through a the method of a intermediary "builder" class.

Joshua Bloch covers this in his book "Effective Java": http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1216151&seqNum=2